# How do i put multiple separate charts onto one pdf in r

Tags: r, statistics, bar-chart, gplots

I am having trouble figuring how to put 6 separate bar plots onto one pdf.
This is one of the plots for example (they are all very similar):

```
    barplot(druhy, ylim = c(0,50), main = "Míváš často chuť na svíčkovou?", col = c("red", "blue", "green", "black", "yellow"))

   legend("topleft", legend = c("ano", "spíše ano", "nevím", "spíše ne", "ne"), fill = c("red", "black", "green", "yellow", "blue"))
```

And here are the values the chart uses:

```
  print(druhy)

  ano\r\n        ne\r\n     nevím\r\n spíše ano\r\n  spíše ne\r\n 
        4             1             2             5             3
```

I tried this code to put them onto one pdf together, but it doesn't work. I am sure there is something wrong in this code, but i just can not seem to find what excactly.

```
    pdf('plot.pdf')

  m <- rbind(c(1,2), c(3,4), c(5,6))
  layout(m)
  sapply(seq_along(sp),
   function(x) {
     dd <- sp[[x]]
     m <- t(`rownames<-`(as.matrix(dd[, -(1:2)]), dd[, 1]))
     bp <- barplot(m,ylim=c(0, 0.4),beside=TRUE,col=barcols)
     title(main=names(sp[x]))
     # abline(h=0)
   }
plot(NA,xlim=c(0,1),ylim=c(0,1),ann=FALSE,axes=FALSE)
```

Is there any better way or how do i fix this code, so the outcome is a pdf with six side by side barplots?
I am a beginner, so I apologize if my question is downright stupid.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The end of plotting must be indicated using `dev.off()`. Here is a simple working example:

```
pdf("myOut.pdf")
for (i in 1:10){
  barplot(iris$Sepal.Length)
}
dev.off()
```